# bash command inside crontab is not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

I have a crontab which runs every minute and removes some directory and files.

My cron looks like this

```
* * * * * bash /var/www/html/Database/Backup/Remove_Old_Backups >/dev/null 2>&1
```

In my log i can see the command running

```
CRON[57937]: (kahoadmin) CMD (bash /var/www/html/Database/Backup/Remove_Old_Backups >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

This is my script file

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOTDIR="/var/www/html/Database/Backup/Backups/*" 
sudo find $ROOTDIR -mtime +5 | xargs rm -f -r
```

If i run this script directly, it i working and removing the directory and files. Only in crontab it is not working

Can anyone help me out in finding what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your permissions are wrong for sudo  (but its also conceivable that you are missing the paths for find and xargs  when running from cron)

If it were me I would  -
1.  Put the file in /etc/crontab and run it as root.
2.  Change it to a 1 line script with fewer dependencies (as i've done often).  I'd put the folowing line in /etc/crontab

```
* * * * * root /bin/find /var/www/html/Database/Backup/Backups mtime +5  -exec rm -rf {}  +
```

Which does the same thing without relying on xargs

I note you are doing a -rf - are you sure you want to be force deleting recursively  - especially an automated process on all subdirectories ?

Comment: I have removed the sudo in script. It worked. Thank you